# Javascript Advanced Closure

Tags: javascript, security, function, code-injection

I am currently working on a project that at one point allows you to type Javascript into a textarea and it will be run. There is a lot of background code monitoring the page and sending to the server data. All of this is in a private function so that one can't break in simply using the console. Then only problem is that the code typed in at the textarea is evaluated inside of the private function containing the server functions, thus giving it access to the site's internals. How can i isolate it and make it so it's scope is outside of the private function? An example is below:

```
<script>

var x = 2;
(function(){
    var x = 10;
    var elem = document.createElement('button');
    elem.addEventListener('click',function(){
        alert(x);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
})();

</script>
```

In this example i want x to return 2 not 10 when the button is pressed. Thus forcing it to run as if it was in the global scope.

## Edit

I have tried binding the function to the window which seemed be going down the right path, but didn't have the effect i was looking for.

```
<script>

var x = 2;
(function(){
    var x = 10;
    var elem = document.createElement('button');
    elem.addEventListener('click',(function(){
        alert(x);
    }).bind(window));
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
})();

</script>
```

I also tried applying the window to the function, but alas that didn't work either.

Comment: "All of this is in a private function so that one can't break in simply using the console." Right, as if people couldn't fake a XHR request with the data you provide in your script. Security and validation do not relate with front-end, you have to do the validation on your back end.

Comment: Well duh, but it forces one to actually read and understand the scripts instead of just messing with variables in the console and it would be somewhat difficult because i am using comet channels and the channel is created and restricted to the private function. Duplicating the channel i think is not allowed once it has been create once in the page. Thus making it much more difficult to use the channel with merely the console.

Comment: You can't access the first `x` declared outside the closure, because it is being shadowed by the `x` declared inside the closure.  If you remove the keyword `var` from the third line, you will have access to that outside variable, but then you will be overwriting its value on that same line (which is now just `x = 10`), which isn't what you want either.  This is one of the many problems generally associated with use of global variables.

Comment: Can use `window.x` if it is in the global scope. No idea whether comet affects that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the answer was much simpler than i had though. A function within the global scope, but outside of the closed function, may be called by any function yet it can only access variables in the global scope. Thus the below example works perfectly.

```
<script>

var run = function(){alert(x);};
var x = 2;
(function(){
    var x = 10;
    var elem = document.createElement('button');
    elem.addEventListener('click',run);
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
})();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **edited** version change alert(x) to alert(**this**.x).
Does it solve your problem ?

Comment: This does work, however because the user is providing the code not me, i can't exactly ask them to type this infront of every variable. You see the purpose is to hide the second x from the user's submitted code.